# Restore plesk 11 via personal FTP

Tags: ftp, migration, backup, restore, plesk

I'm trying to perform data migration from server to server.

My hosting provider allow me a personal FTP to backup all my server data everyday.

I just installed the new server with a Plesk 11 panel manager as the old one (same version).

Now I want to use personal FTP to transfer data (databases, websites, domaines configuration) and get it in the new server.

I did the first part (transfert from personal FTP with ncftp) with success.

Now I have a .tar file (15 GO) containing all my data from the old server, I put it in /var/lib/psa/dump, But I can't find it in Plesk backup manager to perform restore action.

can I do it otherwise ? or Am I messing something here ?

Thank you very much.

**Update: I've used migration tool of plesk (dont need to use backup files anymore) :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used migration tool of plesk (dont need to use backup files anymore) !!

Answer (score 1):

**[Update]**
Instructions for [transfer data through backup/restore](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-installation-upgrade-migration-guide/71256.htm)

---

Has your tar file .discovered folder?
Try to unpack it in /var/lib/psa/dumps/

Plesk backup manager looks for .discovered folder in /var/lib/psa/dumps/.

Here the simple content of this folder:

```
root@deb6x32-plesk11:~# ls -la /var/lib/psa/dumps/
итого 25436
drwxr-xr-x 6 psaadm psaadm     4096 Июн 12 06:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root       4096 Июн  1 00:33 ..
-rw-r----- 1 root   root        222 Июн  5 03:20 backup_file_sharing_1306050318.tgz
-rw-r----- 1 root   root      86569 Июн  5 03:20 backup_info_1306050318.xml
-rw-r----- 1 root   root       3640 Июн  5 03:20 backup_keyXXHyXYaf.key_1306050318.tgz
-rw-r----- 1 root   root   11829416 Июн  5 03:20 backup_sapp-distrib.6915-0_1306050318.tgz
-rw-r----- 1 root   root   11472638 Июн  5 03:20 backup_sapp-distrib.6915-1_1306050318.tgz
-rw-r----- 1 root   root       1426 Июн  5 03:20 backup_sb_server_1306050318.tgz
-rw-r----- 1 root   root      93876 Июн  5 03:20 backup_skel_1306050318.tgz
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root       4096 Июн  1 05:40 clients
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root       4096 Июн  5 03:20 .discovered
drwxr-xr-x 6 root   root       4096 Июн  5 03:20 domains
-rw------- 1 root   root     228263 Июн 12 06:28 mysql.daily.dump.0.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root     232153 Июн 11 06:28 mysql.daily.dump.1.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root     222494 Июн 10 06:26 mysql.daily.dump.2.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root     222405 Июн  9 06:27 mysql.daily.dump.3.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root     221693 Июн  8 06:27 mysql.daily.dump.4.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root     220370 Июн  7 06:26 mysql.daily.dump.5.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root     223990 Июн  6 06:26 mysql.daily.dump.6.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root     220127 Июн  5 06:26 mysql.daily.dump.7.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root     219695 Июн  3 06:26 mysql.daily.dump.8.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root     186857 Июл 27  2013 mysql.preupgrade.11.0.9-11.5.30.20130727-180111.dump.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root     197804 Июн  1 01:56 mysql.preupgrade.11.5.30-11.5.30.20130601-015644.dump.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root       2844 Июл 27  2013 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.11.0.9-11.5.30.20130727-180111.dump.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root       3415 Июл 27  2013 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.11.0.9-11.5.30.20130727-180852.dump.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root       3413 Июн  1 01:56 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.11.5.30-11.5.30.20130601-015646.dump.gz
-rw------- 1 root   root       3413 Июн  1 02:04 mysql.preupgrade.apsc.11.5.30-11.5.30.20130601-020441.dump.gz
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root       4096 Июн  5 03:20 resellers
```

Comment: Thank you @Oleg, I tried to perform restoring action in command line, This is how I did it http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-installation-upgrade-migration-guide/index.htm?fileName=about.htm :)